# Node.js importing JSON to PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql, massivejs

I'm trying to use Node.js to import a JSON file to PostgresSQL. I'm using massive.js to do this.

Below is my JS code:

```
var parsedJSON = require('./employeesTest.json');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var massive = require("massive");
var connectionString = "postgres://:@localhost/tl";

var db = massive.connectSync({ connectionString: connectionString });

var insert = function(err, res) {
for (i = 0; i < parsedJSON.data.length; i++) {
    db.saveDoc("employees", parsedJSON.data[i]);
    if (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
        process.exit(1);
    };
  };
};
```

So. I'm trying to loop through the JSON, and insert.
I'm using this with the following JSON:

```
{
"data": [{
        "id": 89304,
        "userName": "keith1@keith.keith"
    },
    {
        "id": 87431,
        "userName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 84863,
        "userName": null
    },
    {
        "id": 72371,
        "userName": "toad@toad.com"
    }
   ]
  }
```

I have the following PostgresSQL structure:

- **Database:** tl
- **Table:** employees
- **column**: id (Type: Int, Sequence)
- **column**: body (Type: jsonb)

I've seen similar working as per this persons Github:
https://github.com/craigkerstiens/json_node_example

However mine loops, does not error, but does not store any data.

Is there something I am doing fundamentally wrong?

Alternatively, is there the 'best way' of storing an existing JSON file into Postgres using Node.js? I can find a lot of information on Node.js + Postgres, but the majority of it is for RESTful purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`saveDoc` is an asynchronous function, so the way you've written your loop it's sending the data out and then proceeding immediately to check the unset `err` variable. You need to pass `saveDoc` a callback which will receive any error and the results, and do your error checking inside the callback. Since you're iterating over a collection and performing asynchronous work on each member, look into the `map` provided by [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 0):

You didnt wait for saveDoc function

```
db.saveDoc("employees", parsedJSON.data[i]);
```

According to the documentation: https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js

> We can create a document table dynamically by calling saveDoc:
>
> db.saveDoc('test_attributes', {   productVersion: '1.0.5',
>   testEnvironment: 'production',   web: true,   accessibilityStandards:
>   ['wcag2a', 'wcag2aa'] }).then(attributes => {...});

So maybe:

```
db.saveDoc("employees", parsedJSON.data[i]).then((res)=>{
//do something here
});
```